# How to change pitch (sample rate) at run-time with portaudio?

Tags: runtime, portaudio, pitch-shifting

How to change pitch (samplerate) at run-time with portaudio ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Resampling is not a capability of PortAudio. Like the native audio i/o APIs that PortAudio wraps, PA streams run at a constant sample rate. To change the pitch (playback rate) of a sample you need perform on the fly sample rate conversion. You can do this by interpolating the original signal using a phase index that increments at some non-unity rate.

Depending on your requirements you can investigate either resampling/interpolation or pitch-time modification.

Commonly used low to medium quality high performance [polynomial interpolation algorithms for audio](http://www.student.oulu.fi/~oniemita/dsp/deip.pdf) are linear interpolation and [cubic hermite interpolation](http://www.musicdsp.org/archive.php?classid=5#93). Higher quality interpolation can be performed with some variant of [windowed sinc interpolation](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/Interpolation/Windowed_Sinc_Interpolation.html). A library you could use for sinc interpolation is [Secret Rabbit Code](http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/).

For pitch/time transformation (a.k.a. pitch-shifting or time stretching) you might consider using the [DIRAC](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html) library, which has an open source version for mono signals. There are other commercial libraries available e.g. from z-plane research.